# Translate a Binary Float Using Lists/Dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following list:

```
var_list = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
```

I also have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
      id      var
0     H1      010
1     H2      110
2     H3      111
...
4443  H4443   101
```

I would like my new data to look like:

```
      id      var
0     H1      Banana
1     H2      Apple;Banana
2     H3      Apple;Banana;Orange
...
4443  H4443   Apple;Orange
```

Note my dataframe has about 4000 rows and the only solution I can think of so far involves iterating through a loop 4000 times which I would like to avoid, if possible :-/

Similar concept of getting the same original dataframe to look like this

```
      id      apple    banana   orange
0     H1      No       Yes      No
1     H2      Yes      Yes      No
2     H3      Yes      Yes      Yes
...
4443  H4443   Yes      No       Yes
```

EDIT: `var` is a FLOAT not a binary string.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

var_list = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['H1', '010'],
    ['H2', '110'],
    ['H3' , '111']], columns=['id', 'var'])

idx = df['var'].str.split('', expand=True).iloc[:, 1:-1]
idx = idx.T.reset_index(drop=True).T.astype('int32').astype(bool)

var_list = pd.Series(var_list)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': df['id'],
    'var': idx.apply(lambda i: ';'.join(var_list[i]))
})
print(df2)

df3 = pd.concat([
    df[['id']], idx.replace({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})
], axis=1)
df3.columns = ['id', *var_list]
print(df3)
```

prints

| index | id | var |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | H1 | Banana;Orange |
| 1 | H2 | Apple;Banana;Orange |
| 2 | H3 | Orange |

| index | id | Apple | Banana | Orange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | H1 | No | Yes | No |
| 1 | H2 | Yes | Yes | No |
| 2 | H3 | Yes | Yes | Yes |

Answer (score 0):

Write a short function that checks if each corresponding item has a "0" or "1" in place and use it in an apply statement:

```
def subst(row):
    words = []
    for index, contains in enumerate(row["var"]):
         if contains == "1":
             words.append(var_list[index])
    return ";".join(words)

resulting_col = df.apply(subst)
```

Or, since the `for` with an enumerate and the filter are the natural
form for a list comprehension (or, in this case, a generator expression), this can even be written as a one-line
expression using a lambda

```
resulting_col = df.apply(
    lambda row: ";".join(var_list[index] 
        for index, contains  in enumerate(row["var"]) if contains=="1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first define a mapping function and use `pd.Series.map(func)` method to apply the function in your column at once (doc [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)). I assume that this method from pandas is quite optimized.

```py
def binary_to_fruit(binary_str: str) -> str:
    flags = [bit == '1' for bit in list(binary_str)]  # booleans
    out = ''
    for flag, fruit_str in zip(flags, var_list):
        out = out + fruit_str + ';' if flag else out
    out = out[:-1]  # removing last ';' if out is non-empty
    return out

my_df['var'] = my_df['var'].map(binary_to_fruit)
```

Note that `pd.Series.apply(func)` can also be used for basically the same thing.